# Generate pentaho report designer prpt file using java

Tags: java, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

How can I generate Pentaho Report Designer's saved .prpt file using java, without Report Designer itself? Are there any libraries for that?

I need to generate those files programmatically, then, later, open them using Report Designer and fix some values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searches I couldn't find some special library to generate **prpt** file. So I found another way.
The solution is to generate all necessary files & folders inside **prpt** file by yourself (programmatically, or by hand), and then zip them without compression. Then you can just rename extension from **zip** to **prpt**
This prpt file can be opened and modified using Pentaho Report Designer.

Comment: Hello. May I ask you what version of OS and pentaho are you using? I am trying to do so on Linux with Pentaho 3.8.0 prpt file and it is not working. After file is created and compressed, Report Designer can't open it.

Comment: @rRr Hello. I was using Windows7, don't remember Pentaho version. Do not compress the file, just zip it, otherwise PRD won't be able to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Pentaho reporting SDK?  This should give you what you need.

A quick google uncovered this too:

http://www.ambientelivre.com.br/downloads/doc_download/83-embedding-pentaho-reporting-engine.html

Comment: Yes, I looked to this document. And it's not appropriate to my question. This documentation is about how to use Pentaho Reporting SDK. This sdk uses already available **prpt** file and produces excel file for example. But I need to generate this **prpt** file programmatically, without gui interface (like Report Designer)

Comment: hmm i wondered if that was the case, i've definitely seen examples somewhere for generating prpt's.  Try posting on the pentaho forums - the reporting architect checks those pretty often.